# bundle cannot build gem native extension while gem can - json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, bundle, bundler

I know, yet another question of the kind, but nothing helped so far.

When I run `bundle install` on the production server I get the following error:

```
...
Installing json (1.6.3) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 

Gem files will remain installed in /home/onblimp/onblimp/releases/20111213131738/RAILS_ENV=production/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/onblimp/onblimp/releases/20111213131738/RAILS_ENV=production/ruby/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.3/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.6.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run `gem install json -v '1.6.3'` it installs without error. I'm running both commands as a root. In development it works well. A few days ago it also worked well.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No (not on the production server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue by simply restarting the server. It would be great to know the cause, but I guess that's too much to ask.

Answer (score 0):

hey i got the same error .I installed xcode and restart my mac.Then i made new project in rails and got into this

```
**Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted
An error occured while installing json (1.6.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.6.3'` succeeds before bundling**
```

i just did **sudo gem install json -v '1.6.3'** it worked fine in my case.